# PHP Password Hashing

Tags: php, passwords, password-protection

As of now I have this line of code

```
<?php
    $pass = "12312312";
    echo md5(crypt($pass))
?>
```

I know crypt can randomly generate salt but I don't have any idea how can I compare it on the user input.

What are the fields do I need for my log in table?
and also, what data will I insert to my table?

thanks!

Comment: md5 is broken, so you should use something else. try bcrypt.

Comment: thanks!! but what fields do I need?

hmm can I insert both the password with salt in 1 field? or I need to have a salt field ?

Comment: You will need to store the salt in it's own field.

Comment: this is my table structure

tblogin

user_id
username
password
salt

is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store password in table as below

```
$pass = "12312312";

// store this in table with separate column
$salt = md5("any variable"); // may be email or username

// generate password
$password = sha1($salt.$pass);

// now store salt and password in table
```

And you can check password like

```
$pass = "User input";

// get the user from database based on user id or username
// and test the password stored in db with

if($passwordFromTable == sha1($saltFromTable.$pass))
{
    // correct
}
```